# Where do I put a recurring script that updates database from api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, rake

I have a Rails app set up with a model Account that should be updated every morning with data coming from an external API I'm calling (a CRM). Basically either I create new accounts in my app that I find in the CRM and some of the fields that are mapped with my columns, either I find the account if it already exists and I update it.

So far, I've been putting this code into the `seeds.rb` file and from Heroku, where the app is hosted, I set up a scheduler with the command : `rails db:seed` that runs periodically.

My issue is that I'm sure there is a better way of doing this. I've read about rake tasks but I did not quite understand how that applied to my case. Otherwise I thought of putting my method in the `models/account.rb` file as a self method. But I don't really know how I can invoke it in a rake command to allow me to set up a scheduler in Heroku.

Any idea on where would be the best place to put this method, and how to call it from command line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `script` directory in your project, and put your script from `db/seeds.rb` into this directory, maybe called `update_accounts.rb`.  Then you can run it with

```
rails runner script/update_accounts.rb
```

and schedule that task in heroku. More info about [rails runner here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a background processor such as Sidekiq: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Once using Sidekiq, you need a scheduler like https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler to make sure it happens periodically as you require.

This will become easier to maintain as your application grows and you need more *workers*. It also moves your scheduling into version control.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ropeney, it seems to be something that I need to dig into, although it seems a bit overkill for the size of the application I'm building. Will look into it.